# Fastest way to bcrypt 3 million records

Tags: php, csv, bcrypt

We've inherited a system which has 3 million user logins, in a CSV broken into chunks of 500k, with unhashed passwords.

The client against advice, has decided he wants to keep the same passwords but just hash them for the new system, rather then forcing users to set new passwords, so please no replies saying "just dont do it".

We're currently using PHP to process the file to normalise the data and bcrypt the existing strings.

However running a test on 200 records, the moment we add bcrypt into the loop the process takes around 7 seconds longer.

Over time this will obviously stack up considerably.

---

Does anybody have other suggestions how we can convert the strings to bcrypt with more speed? I was thinking maybe there was a command line tool which we could pass the CSV into and it "knew column 4" was the password, and hash it, then save back to the file or something.

Any suggestions at this point are welcome.

It would be worth saying we need to repeat this process on the launch day so it needs to be appropriate to do with minimal downtime?

Many thanks

---

*Update*

For those who are interested, on a 2012 MBP with 2.6Ghz i7 and 8GB ram it took 9 hours to complete the initial round running 6 instances of the script each instance processing 500k users.

Comment: You could simply add a flag to the table row stating it's not been updated. Then when the user logs in, encrypt the password and mark it as updated. This will also double up as a way of weeding out unused accounts.

Comment: Having plain text passwords in the database is a terrible idea, don't do this...if you really want to go over that many records, you could use GO ( https://gobyexample.com/goroutines ) to run concurrent goroutines, making things considerably faster than using PHP (even with pcntl)

Comment: @Twisted1919 The point of password encryption is to burn CPU utilization, running more instances than CPUs does not make sense.

Comment: It is not that bad. assuming a password hash tine of 100ms:  2,500,000 / 10 / 3600 / 24 = < 3 days.

Comment: @Doug wouldnt be up for that, as would mean storing the plain text passwords for potentially prolonged period of time

Comment: @Twisted1919 would be interested to look into this, but having no experience in Go, would probs take longer to do it in that than waiting for the import xD

Comment: Sorry I read the question as md5 hashed for some reason. If they were already hashed you would just check against the old method whether it was correct, then if so rehash the submitted password. This clearly isn't a great solution if they are all in plain form. If that's the case I think biting the bullet and getting them encrypted correctly is your only option.

Comment: However a combination of both options, running concurrently may work. Begin your switch process as mentioned which may well take a long time but while it's running also have function that fires on login, Just ensuring your batch script doesn't touch any with a changed flag.

Comment: **GNU Parallel** can probably speed things up manyfold.

Comment: @MarkSetchell would it be faster than just letting it run vs trying to set all that up first xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the fact that bcrypt is slow is kind of the point - it's supposed to be slow to make it more resistant to brute-force cracking.

Only a couple options I can think of:

1. Divvy up the task and use more threads/processors/computers.
2. Use a lower "complexity" factor.  This will make the hashing faster, but decrease the security of the hashes somewhat, so not a very good option.

As for making the process run quicker on launch day to avoid downtime, here's what I would suggest:

1. Bcrypt all 2.5 million accounts now and store the bcrypt hashes in your new system with the user accounts.
2. Additionally, compute a simple SHA hash of the passwords and store that in a file offline with the associated user ID.
3. On go live day, get all the accounts again from the legacy system.  For new accounts created after step 1, create the accounts in the new system with the Bcrypt hash.  For other accounts, check if the SHA hash (quick to compute) matches the SHA hash in the file you created in step 2.  If not, re-bcrypt the password and update the new system.  If they match, then no need to bcrypt again.

Comment: Number two is a really bad solution, it increases the risk to the users. With 2.5 million users the server is a prime target.

Comment: I didnt think of distributing the import across different processes/systems! Currently we've got 6 csvs, and the server we're getting has 96gb ram, so I think maybe we can just run the script 6 times, so each process will process 500k. and I like the idea of the hashing to check for recent changes as we can drop this whole column once we go live so the data is for all purposes gone. Does anybody see any downsides to doing something like this or does it seem fairly sensible?

Answer (score 2):

Give the CSV a new field `PasswordHash`. At the launch day it is empty for all clients. For a transition period the authentication code checks the user credentials against the plain passwords **and** against the hashed ones. During the following hours/days/weeks a background process hashes all passwords and delete the plain ones.

Comment: This sounds like we'd be storing the plain text passwords in the database, this is a no go for us, so would want to avoid doing this.